# Saving/Loading data with a javascript (task manager app)

Tags: javascript, save, load

So I want to write a simple task manager as a part of my learning process using javascript and run it without a server. I want to be able to save/load so-called 
"projects" - lists of related tasks and their corresponding status 
(in-process/done). These projects must be stored in different data files on my disc drive (in txt files for exmpl)

What is the simplest way to achieve that ? What are the alternatives ? I am very new to programming and would appreciate some help

Comment: I think you're going to have to explain yourself better, put code, examples ...

Comment: You won't be able to combine "without a server" and "stored [...] on my disc drive" as the browser can't save data to your drive. Either fire up a Node.js server (which allows you to use Javascript for the server side as well, so it should fit your learning requirements), or create a REST backend in some other language.

Comment: @JLe That’s not quite right. Have look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file
And (if you don’t insist on saved files) you can use your browsers local storage, too. All just for local use!

Comment: @Matthi Fair enough, but the complexity of not only using, but also writing code to support download/upload of files as replacement of save/load just ins't worth it. But local storage is a great solution though.

Comment: Thanks, It's pretty complicated but possible